# Github: Clone a Repository, Make Changes to the Clone, and Commit to Original Repository

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, github

I am new to using Github.

I am studying Ruby on Rails with a computer and successfully pushed everything to my github repository as well as to Heroku.

Now I am using a computer different from the first one I used.

The question is, how do I clone my github repository, make changes to the code, and push those changes to the original repository in github, and hopefully carry those changes to Heroku as well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you clone a repository from github (and you are logged in form github)
You have 3 options / links to "clone" your Repo.

1. SSH
2. HTTP
3. GIT read only

If you are not logged in, only 2 options appear

1. HTTP (read only)
2. GIT read only

In the file .git/config you can see which one you added, mostly under [remote "origin"]

```
url = git@github.com:username/project.git (SSH)

url = https://username@github.com/username/project.git (HTTP)

url = https://github.com/username/project.git (HTTP Read only)

url = git://github.com/username/project.git (Git Read only)
```

If you choose a read only, the best you can do is remove that remote with:

`git remote rm origin`

After that you can add a new remote:

`git remote add origin https://username@github.com/username/project.git` (for http)

or

`git remote add origin git@github.com:username/project.git` (for SSH)

HTTPS is the most easy to set up, but you will have to enter your password for every push / pull (unless you want to store your password plaintext)

After setting up the remote, you can push with `git push origin branchname`

More information can be found on the git manual page: http://help.github.com/remotes/

Comment: I cannot find the read-only url not matter if I am logged in or not.
I have only the https and the ssh urls, but no one is marked as read-only